# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models' when I load my Pytorch Model using torch.load(modelpath)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, machine-learning, pytorch

I am getting the following error when I try to load my saved Pytorch model.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models'
```

The way I am loading the model is : `model = torch.load(r'Models-BERT\model-duplicates dropped(sampled)_v2', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))`

I saved the model using: `torch.save(model, 'Models-BERT/model-duplicates dropped(sampled)_v2')`

The version of transformers used: 3.4.0

also tested on transformers version 4.12.2

So far I have tried upgrading the transformers library, I have tried the solution provided in the similar question on StackOverflow here:[StackOverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822496/no-module-named-transformers-models-while-trying-to-import-berttokenizer) but nothing worked.
I also ran my code on Azure notebook and on my local system, both are giving same error.

When I run the same snippet on Azure, I am getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.modeling_bert'
```

What could be the issue here? And how can I run this code?

Comment: Could you please refer this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18325#issuecomment-600457228 may it helps.