# No module named 'transformers.models.ernie_m.configuration_ernie_m'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, haystack

So I am trying to use Haystack to run a model in Google Colab. I am using [this](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/01_basic_qa_pipeline) tutorial and I am adapting it to my project.

My problem is in the initialization of the reader:

```
from haystack.nodes import FARMReader

reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path="deepset/roberta-base-squad2", use_gpu=True)
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    618             return default
    619 
--> 620     def __bool__(self):
    621         return bool(self.keys())
    622 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py in _load_attr_from_module(self, model_type, attr)
    614     def get(self, key, default):
    615         try:
--> 616             return self.__getitem__(key)
    617         except KeyError:
    618             return default

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py in getattribute_from_module(module, attr)
    559     if module != transformers_module:
    560         try:
--> 561             return getattribute_from_module(transformers_module, attr)
    562         except ValueError:
    563             raise ValueError(f"Could not find {attr} neither in {module} nor in {transformers_module}!")
```

and this:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.ernie_m.configuration_ernie_m because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'transformers.models.ernie_m.configuration_ernie_m'
```

I don't get this error all the time, but only sometimes and there is no pattern. I do not understand how ernie_m is related to roberta-base-squad2 since according to [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/ernie) it's a separate model.

For reference, I already import earlier:

```
!pip install transformers
import transformers
from transformers import pipeline
```

and:

```
from haystack.nodes import FARMReader
from transformers.models.bert.tokenization_bert import BasicTokenizer
```

The only other similar problem I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66822496/no-module-named-transformers-models-while-trying-to-import-berttokenizer) and I do not think that it helps my case, right? Thank you in advance for your effort and time.

Comment: I think you'll have to show more of your code to help us help you debug the issue(s). If you just do a fresh install and import, it works out of the box. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bXNKk6rbPPBZN0doC2c736NWKb18tfiG?usp=sharing

Comment: I agree with @alvas.
Also, you should not install `transformers` separately (it is automatically installed with `haystack`).

If you want a quick feedback, you can reach the Deepset team and the Haystack community through Github discussions (github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/discussions) or Discord (haystack.deepset.ai/community)

Comment: Yeah I know that the code I give you is not enough for I have no idea from where to start. I did not add much more than the tutorial I added in the hyperlink. I have just changed the files I am using. 
I was guessing that it has to do with the double installation of transformers. As I said 9/10 of the times it works and 1/10 of the times it doesn't. Now, i am importing `transformers` only once as Stefano said. I will add further details if I find a clue